# How to reset or clear the bootstrap datetimepicker?

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

How to reset or clear the datetimepicker? I can't find solution for this bootstrap datetimepicker version. I don't want to use the default clear. As you can see there's a highlighted day, using a reset it should clear the highlighted day and display the plain datetimepicker.

```js
$('.select2').select2({

});

$('#apptDay').datetimepicker({
  format: 'L'
});

$("#apptDay").on("show.datetimepicker update.datetimepicker", function(e) {
  highlight()
});

function highlight() {
  var dateToHilight = ["11/21/2022", "11/25/2022", "12/30/2022"];
  var array = $("#apptDay").find(".day").toArray();

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var date = array[i].getAttribute("data-day");

    if (dateToHilight.indexOf(date) > -1) {
      array[i].style.color = "orange";
      array[i].style.fontWeight = "bold";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://rawgit.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4/master/build/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css'>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://rawgit.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4/master/build/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js'></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Select Doctor</label>
    <span class="text-danger">*</span>
    <select class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" style="width: 100%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
      <option selected="selected">Alabama</option>
      <option>Alaska</option>
      <option>California</option>
      <option>Delaware</option>
      <option>Tennessee</option>
      <option>Texas</option>
      <option>Washington</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 mt-4">
    <div class="input-group date" id="apptDay" data-target-input="nearest">
      <input name="day" type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#apptDay" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" value="" />

      <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#apptDay" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As per the above snippet, when you click outside of the datepicker, it is clearing the date. so what you want to do?

Comment: I updated the question, run the snippet again

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai : If i click outside before selecting a date, the current date remains in the input field (tested in chrome, firefox and edge)...

Comment: I mean clearing the highlighted date of 21 and 25 that's what I mean

Comment: I know how to clear the highlighted styles, but i don't know where or how to reset the picker...

Comment: there is a ``hide`` event, but i think you mean something else...

Comment: this is my logic sir because I will use it in ajax, when the dropdown value changed for example, the datetimepicker will show the available date which is 21 or 25 when the dropdown value change again it will now show different highlighted days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to remove the styles if you set a class (instead of modifying the `style` property):

```js
if (dateToHilight.indexOf(date) > -1) {
  array[i].classList.add('highlighted');
}
```

and define the styles with CS:

```css
.highlighted {
  color: orange;
  font-weight: bold;  
}
```

Then you could simply remove that class in any case, you want:

```js
$('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');
```

To highlight different dates depending on the value of a `select` element, you could define a global var (maybe `country`) and save the value of the select in this var:

```js
var country = 'Alabama';

$(".select2").on("change", function() {
  country = $(this).val();
});
```

Then you only need to define your dates, that you want to highlight in a multi dimension array or object with the values of the `select` element as keys:

```js
var dateToHilight = {
    'Alabama': ["11/21/2022", "11/25/2022"],
    'Alaska': ["11/23/2022", "11/29/2022"],
    'California': ["11/17/2022", "11/18/2022"],
    'Delaware': ["11/19/2022", "11/26/2022"],
    'Tennessee': ["11/20/2022", "11/30/2022"],
    'Texas': ["11/15/2022", "11/24/2022"],
    'Washington': ["11/14/2022", "11/27/2022"],
};
```

and modify the highlighting `if` to select the second dimension with that key:

```js
if (dateToHilight[country].indexOf(date) > -1) {
  array[i].classList.add('highlighted');
}
```

**Working example:** (for demonstration with a `keyup` event)

```js
var country = 'Alabama';

$('.select2').select2({});

$('#apptDay').datetimepicker({
  format: 'L'
});

$("#apptDay").on("show.datetimepicker update.datetimepicker", function() {
  highlight();
});

$(".select2").on("change", function() {
  country = $(this).val();
});

function highlight() {
  var dateToHilight = {
    'Alabama': ["11/21/2022", "11/25/2022"],
    'Alaska': ["11/23/2022", "11/29/2022"],
    'California': ["11/17/2022", "11/18/2022"],
    'Delaware': ["11/19/2022", "11/26/2022"],
    'Tennessee': ["11/20/2022", "11/30/2022"],
    'Texas': ["11/15/2022", "11/24/2022"],
    'Washington': ["11/14/2022", "11/27/2022"],
  };
  var array = $("#apptDay").find(".day").toArray();

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var date = array[i].getAttribute("data-day");

    if (dateToHilight[country].indexOf(date) > -1) {
      array[i].classList.add('highlighted');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.highlighted {
  color: orange;
  font-weight: bold;  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://rawgit.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4/master/build/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css'>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://rawgit.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4/master/build/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js'></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Select Doctor</label>
    <span class="text-danger">*</span>
    
    <select class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" style="width: 100%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
      <option selected="selected">Alabama</option>
      <option>Alaska</option>
      <option>California</option>
      <option>Delaware</option>
      <option>Tennessee</option>
      <option>Texas</option>
      <option>Washington</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-sm-6 mt-4">
    <div class="input-group date" id="apptDay" data-target-input="nearest">
      <input name="day" type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#apptDay" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" value="" />

      <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#apptDay" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have one more question is 'on change'  applicable for that?

Comment: In which context? ``$("#apptDay input").on("change"...`` doesn't work...

Comment: dropdown of another element

Comment: Could you please add it to your question? (use the "Edit" button)

Comment: I updated the snippet, everytime I change the value in select option it should trigger the remove class highlighted same concept in your keyup

Comment: I added your ``select`` element, but a simple removement would be useless, because everytime you open the datepicker the function ``highlight`` is called again. Therefor i modified your ``dateToHilight`` array, to highlight different days depending on the selected country...